# Only child in CSS with a text sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to make the following inner span disappear, if it's an only child:

```
<div class="foo">
  <span></span>  
</div>
```

i.e. the selector should not work in this case:

```
<div class="foo">
  <span></span>  
  Some text
</div>
```

I tried `:only-child` and `:last-child` which don't work, I assume because of that "Some text" text.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Are you asking how to hide all the elements inside the div with class 'foo'? If that is what you mean why don't you use: div.foo:empty { display: none } and hide the whole thing if empty?

Comment: @Ionut Yes it wasn't clear enough, I updated it.

Comment: Have you tried .foo span:empty:first-child ? Also, in your code the span it's always the only child. The 'Some text' text is not a child.

Comment: @Ionut If there is "Some text" then I don't want to hide it. So I tried `span:last-child` which doesn't work, it always hides it.

Comment: @Ionut Yes that's what I thought... the text is not an element. So is there any way to deal with that?

Comment: I think this cannot be done with only CSS. You should use jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: only the span should be invisible or both text and span?

Comment: A pure CSS solution would need an extra element around `Some text` and existing span coming after this extra element (then reordered with flexbox or float or whatever). Then you could select the latter whether or not it comes after the extra element e.g. it's the :first-child or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this cannot be done with only CSS. You should use jQuery or JavaScript by making some conditions.

```
if ($(".foo").text().length < 1 && $('.foo span').is(':empty')) {
    //hide your element here
    $('.foo').hide();
}
```