# Select element inline with text

Tags: html, css, image, text, css-selectors

I want to select an element that is inside a parent , sourrounded by text (and than an element that isn't), for instance:

```html
<div>
Lorem Ipsum
<img src="..."><!-- <<< Select this-->
dolor sit amet
</div>
<div>
<img src=""><!-- <<< not this-->
</div>
```

My basic idea is to make single emojis bigger and set emojis inline with text to `1rem` (in a chat application, as WhatsApp, Signal, Discord... do).

I'm using Twemoji, so emojis get translated to images

**`:only-child()` won't work for me since text doesn't count as an additional child**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not possible without changing your markup or using JavaScript. I found many questions matching your own, none with solutions.

[Is there a CSS selector for the first child, taking text nodes into account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074295/is-there-a-css-selector-for-the-first-child-taking-text-nodes-into-account)

[Only child in CSS with a text sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341927/only-child-in-css-with-a-text-sibling)

[CSS selector for only child, including text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805715/css-selector-for-only-child-including-text)

[CSS: first-child selector including text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179642/css-first-child-selector-including-text-nodes)

[CSS element child vs child with text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994806/css-element-child-vs-child-with-text-node)

[How to use CSS first-child but excluding text content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088605/how-to-use-css-first-child-but-excluding-text-content)

Answer (score 1):

There can be many possible ways. One is to enclose the text into a `span` or `p` tag like

```
<div>
    <p>
    Lorem Ipsum
        <img src="..."><!-- <<< Select this-->
    dolor sit amet
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src=""><!-- <<< not this-->
</div>
```

and then use the css selector `div > p > img`.

Another easier way would be to use classes or id's like

```
<div>
    Lorem Ipsum
        <img src="..." class="select-this-class"><!-- <<< Select this-->
    dolor sit amet
</div>
<div>
    <img src=""><!-- <<< not this-->
</div>
```

and then use the css selector `.select-this-class`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried giving the div and img tag a class or id. you can do something like

```
.divclass > .imgclass{
//write css here
}
```

Comment: That would select all images, including the ones that are sourrounded by text. Nevertheless, thanks for your effort